# Understanding lvalue concept

Tags: c++

I've read about `lvalue` concept in `c++ 14 N3797` working draft and I have a question about it. The Standard says:

sec. 3.10/1 N3797:

> **Expressions** are categorized according to the taxonomy in Figure 1.
>
> —An
>   lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the
>   left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or
>   an object. [Example: If E is an expression of pointer type, then *E is
>   an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which E
>   points. As another example, the result of calling a function whose
>   return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. —end example]

It's ok at first glance. But the sec. 5/1 N3797 provides a definition of the expression. It says:

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a
>   computation

Now consider sec. 5.4/1:

> The result of the expression (T)cast-expression is of type T. The
>   result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue
>   reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference
>   to object type; otherwise the result is a prvalue.

We have that `lvalue` is an expression by definition (I.e. sequence of operators and operands), and the result of an `lvalue` is an `lvalue` (also a sequnce of operators and operands). It is not clear for me how an expression can return an expression after evaluation (lvalue returns lvalue in the quote from 5.4/1 that I cited).

Could you possibly explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just slightly sloppy wording.

In C++ (as well as in C), an "lvalue" is a kind of expression. Rather than

> The result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue ...

it should say:

> The *expression* is an lvalue if T is an lvalue ...

The meaning of the word "lvalue" has varied over the years and from one language to another. If I recall correctly, the original idea was that an "lvalue" was a kind of value, and an expression could be evaluated either for its lvalue (determining what object it designates) or for its rvalue (determining a value). Perhaps the author(s) had that meaning in mind when writing that sentence.

Comment: It looks quite logically. Thanks for answer!

Comment: One more clarification: If an expression is evaluated as rvalue whether we have a copy of an object's value that expression returns?

Comment: @St.Antario That depends on a lot of things and can't be answered in general.

Comment: @St.Antario: Evaluating an expression as an rvalue means getting the value (in the usual sense) of the expression. There isn't necessarily an *object* at all; for example `2+2` is an expression with an lvalue.